# An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'xxx' is invalid

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, rdl

I've a VB application which will use .rdl to generate reports in PDF format by using ***Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms***.

There is an features which we allow the application to run without showing any UI to generate certain reports based on the setting in database. And we use task scheduler to run the application daily in the morning to generate some daily reports.

We have few client is using the same application with same rdl reports. But 1 of the client is keep getting the issue when task scheduler trigger the application while others is working fine.

The application will basically generate 11 reports everyday in the morning, but 1 of the report is keep throwing the exception whenever the task scheduler trigger it in the morning.

> Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: 
>   An error occurred during local report processing. Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'xxx.rdl' is invalid.

But when we could not replicate the issue when we trigger the task scheduler or run the program manually afterwards.

Full error stack:

```
Error Message : Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report 'D:\EASI\AutoReport\SSRSReport\Report\1tic_movie_tax_report.rdl' is invalid. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: An unexpected error occurred in Report Processing. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GetLocationEvidence(SafePEFileHandle peFile, SecurityZone& zone, StringHandleOnStack retUrl)
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateLocationEvidence()
   at System.Security.Policy.PEFileEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.AssemblyEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidence(Type type, Boolean markDelayEvaluatedEvidenceUsed)
   at System.Security.Policy.AppDomainEvidenceFactory.GenerateEvidence(Type evidenceType)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.GetHostEvidenceNoLock(Type type)
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.RawEvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Security.Policy.Evidence.EvidenceEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetEvidenceInfo(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath, String& typeName)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetTypeAndHashSuffix(AppDomain appDomain, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.RequireCompleteInit(IInternalConfigRecord record)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Xml.Schema.Parser..ctor(SchemaType schemaType, XmlNameTable nameTable, SchemaNames schemaNames, ValidationEventHandler eventHandler)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel2005.Upgrade.UpgradeSerializerSettings2005.CreateReaderSettings()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.RdlObjectModel2005.Upgrade.UpgradeImpl2005.CreateReaderSettings()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RDLUpgrader.RdlUpgrader.UpgradeFrom200501(XmlReader xmlReader, Boolean throwUpgradeException, Boolean upgradeDundasCRIToNative, Boolean renameInvalidDataSources, RDLUpgradeResult& upgradeResults)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RDLUpgrader.RdlUpgrader.UpgradeUnified(Stream stream, XmlReader xmlReader, String namespaceURI, Boolean throwUpgradeException, Boolean upgradeDundasCRIToNative, Boolean renameInvalidDataSources, RDLUpgradeResult& upgradeResults)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RDLUpgrader.RdlUpgrader.Upgrade(Stream stream, Boolean throwUpgradeException, Boolean upgradeDundasCRIToNative, Boolean renameInvalidDataSources, RDLUpgradeResult& upgradeResults)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.RDLUpgrader.UpgradeToCurrent(Stream stream, Boolean throwUpgradeException, Boolean renameInvalidDataSources, RDLUpgradeResult& upgradeResults)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.RdlObjectModelUpgradeStrategy.Upgrade(Stream definitionStream)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.Phase1(Stream definitionStream, String& description, String& language, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportPublishing.ReportPublishing.InternalCreateIntermediateFormat(Stream definitionStream, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileOdpReport(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, DataSetInfoCollection& sharedDataSetReferences, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks, Byte[]& dataSetsHash)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(PublishingContext reportPublishingContext, IDataProtection dataProtection)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(ICatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(PreviewItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
   at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
   at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.GetParameters()
   at SSRSReport.frmSsrsReport.SetReportParameter(String ReportTitle)
   at SSRSReport.frmSsrsReport.ViewReport(Boolean showSplash)
   at SSRSReport.frmMain.GenerateAutoReports(DateTime selectedDate)
```

Code:

```
1. rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = fileName : executed on function [SSRSReport.frmSsrsReport.ViewReport]
2. rptViewer.LocalReport.GetParameters() : executed on function [SSRSReport.frmSsrsReport.SetReportParameter]
```

Answer (score 1):

The main message error is same with my problem, but the details are little bit different.

At my case, I need to install [MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER 2015 RUNTIME](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45496) then the problem gone.

HTH

Comment: this resolved it for me now too. Everything was working fine for me until I updated Visual studio 2019 (I think had broken it but not sure). I now installed report viewer 2015 runtime then restarted my machine. It just started to work again

Answer (score 1):

Same Error today:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report  'fileName.rdlc' is invalid. --->
```

The Case is when I develop using old VS2015, and now trying to use VS2019 with the RDLC tool..
The designer is upgrading rdlc file.

I must restore my rdlc file and back to old VS2015, and re-publish it..